# Can I release different versions of my extension to testers before other users?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I know you can create a separate hidden or private extension. I'm looking for a way to release the newest version of my extension only to beta users before I publish it to everyone within one listing in the chrome web store so I don't have to maintain two separate extensions.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way. You can publish an extension to a limited number of testers through a Google Group but if your extension is public you have to first unpublish it. Your best option is to create a second item for testers to use.